# use URL passed values in django views and render it to template

Tags: django

Views.py

```
class citydetailview(generic.DetailView):
   #Generic class-based list view for a list of cities.
    model = City
    def get_city_value(request, pk):
        if pk==1:
            hyd=Type_city1.objects.all()
        elif pk==2:
            hyd=Type_city2.objects.all()
        elif pk==3:
            hyd=Type_city3.objects.all()
        return (request,{'hyd':hyd})
```

urls.py

```
path('city/<int:pk>', views.citydetailview.as_view(), name='city_ads_detail'),
```

I want to use the 'pk' value from the urls.py in one of my class and render the output accordingly to template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than, why not use a List View:

```
class CityDetailView(generic.ListView):
    model = City

    def get_queryset(self):
        city_type = self.kwargs['city_type']
        if city_type == 1:
            return Type_city1.objects.all()
        elif city_type == 2:
            return Type_city2.objects.all()
        elif city_type == 3:
            return Type_city3.objects.all()

        return super().get_queryset()

# urls
path('city/<int:city_type>/', views.CityDetailView.as_view(), name='city_ads_detail'),
```

Finally, probably its better to share your models as well. Because I think your model structure probably isn't right. Rather than having different `Type_city` models, you could have stored them in a single model and filter based on a field ie `city_type`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have added my models.py for your reference. Thanks Jai